# disable back button on in ltk wizardinputpage

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, wizard, back, ltk

I'm doing a plugin in Eclipse IDE in order to do a refactoring. I'm using LTK, the point is: I don't know how I can disabled the back button after the preview. I've tried to create the RefactoringWizard using some flags like 'NO_BACK_BUTTON_ON_STATUS_DIALOG', but I think it is not the rigth way to do it.

The poblem I have in the background is that when I push preview and then push back, and preview again, the preview box shows the change related with the refactoring twice!.

I think the best solution is disabling the back button after the preview because this is the solution I have seen in others plugins.

Sorry because of my English and thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog#updateButtons`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse/jface/3.6.1/org/eclipse/jface/wizard/WizardDialog.java#1326) disables the back button when `currentPage.getPreviousPage()` returns `null`. So, I suggest you to override the method [`org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard#getPreviousPage`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.ltk.ui/refactoring/3.5.0/org/eclipse/ltk/ui/refactoring/RefactoringWizard.java#RefactoringWizard.getPreviousPage%28org.eclipse.jface.wizard.IWizardPage%29) to return `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't run. I have put the code below:
 
 `public IWizardPage getPreviousPage(IWizardPage page) {
  return null;
 }`

overriding the old one. After pushing the preview button, the back button is still enabled.

Eclipse also show me the flag that says 'Override org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard#getPreviousPage'.

I think it can't be so hard but I do not have idea.

Comment: Did you debug the program? I suggest to put a break point inside your method to see when it gets invoked and how the caller reacts on the return value of your method. I'd also suggest you to put a break point at `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog#updateButtons` to get more insight about how it decides to show or hide the back button.

Comment: I have tried it. I have put a breakpoint at _org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog#updateButtons_ and it is not called. Could it be possible that my app use another method to set the state of the buttons?

Comment: It's ok I think the problem is that the back button I want to disable is the one that appears after pressing the preview button. Anyway, I have solved the problem in a different way because of my concrete situation. Thanks for all!